# How to insert comments in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to see if anyone could help me with this. I wanted to see how to insert a comment into my page and have it update on the spot but the problem is, I am not sure how to do it. I have tried to look like sites like this one I don't know how to get it to work correctly since even with looking at the source, it doesn't really seem to help. This is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- 
this is a comment, the above indicates the formal document type 
(like what a file extension does, but as part of the document)
-->
<html>

<head>
  <!-- the head section is things that aren't visible on the page, like the title -->
  <title>Da Blog</title>

  <!-- we'll put lots more in here later -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- the body is where the visible stuff goes -->

  <br/><br/><br/>
  <hr>
  <h1>My Uber Fake Blog</h1>
  <hr>

  <p>
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
</p>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Add a comment</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="comment_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="textbox" id="comment_name" placeholder="Name"
             class="input-large form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="60" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"
             class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="post" class="btn">Post</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="comment_list">
    <div class="panel panel-default comment">
        <div class="panel-heading">etomai</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            This is my comment.  I think the post is too long.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default comment">
        <div class="panel-heading">etomai</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            This is my comment.  I think the post is too long.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using JavaScript? What's the point of doing this?

Comment: I too am curious for the use case. Surely someone looking at the DOM will also have access to the console messages. Why not just use `console.log()`?

Comment: I've begun to think that you may have not been clear in what you meant by _comment_; when talking about _JavaScript_, `// this` and `/* this */` is a comment and when talking about _HTML/DOM_, `<!--this-->` is a comment. However, I'm starting to think you meant just normal _HTMLElements_. Read the MDN references for `document.createElement`, `node.appendChild`, `node.insertBefore`, `node.cloneNode` and perhaps `document.getElementById` to learn about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to adding a *HTMLElement* to the *DOM Tree*, a *Comment* is also a *Node* (*nodeType* `8`) and will work in the same way. Use [`document.createComment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createComment) to make a new one, and you can modify the *data* property to change it's contents.

Comment: I like the idea but the problem is, I am not too sure how to implement it. I would assume that it places it on the bottom of the page as well. Is there anyway to get it to place it on the top of the comment stack instead?

Comment: Comment stack? It gets placed wherever you append/insert it.