# Blog comments that update upon submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm going to try and be as clear as possible. I have some code but I am not sure how to get it to clone the comments and insert new comments with the inputted text from the user into this piece of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- 
this is a comment, the above indicates the formal document type 
(like what a file extension does, but as part of the document)
-->
<html>

<head>
  <!-- the head section is things that aren't visible on the page, like the title -->
  <title>Da Blog</title>

  <!-- we'll put lots more in here later -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.css" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- the body is where the visible stuff goes -->

  <br/><br/><br/>
  <hr>
  <h1>My Uber Fake Blog</h1>
  <hr>

  <p>
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
This is a wall of text for my uber fake blog!!!!
</p>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Add a comment</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="comment_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="textbox" id="comment_name" placeholder="Name"
             class="input-large form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="60" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"
             class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="post" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Post</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="comment_list">
    <div class="panel panel-default comment">
        <div class="panel-heading">etomai</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            This is my comment.  I think the post is too long.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default comment">
        <div id="Commentinblog" class="panel-heading">etomai</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            This is my comment.  I think the post is too long.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

I have tried this to see if I can at least start getting somewhere on getting it started.

```
function myFunction()
{
// Create a new, plain <span> element
var sp1 = document.createElement("div");

// Get a reference to the element, before we want to insert the element
var sp2 = document.getElementById("Commentinblog");
// Get a reference to the parent element
var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;

// Insert the new element into the DOM before sp2
parentDiv.insertBefore(sp1, sp2);
}
```

but I can't seem to quite wrap my head around how this all works. The w3schools site helped me understand the basic but it's still a difficult concept that I am trying to wrap my head around. Can anyone help me figure out how to clone this with the user inputted comments and text and update it. Also, if anyone can help me understand it better.

Comment: Before we go anywhere: These won't work like regular comments, because they won't be saved anywhere. They'll go away when you refresh the page. Are you sure this is what you want to do? (I'm guessing that you're simultaneously submitting them to the server?)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do, I don't mind that I can't save them yet. I just want to be sure that I can insert comments

Comment: [Same question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950672/how-to-insert-comments-in-page) For the future please try to edit / improve the existing question instead of opening a new one if it is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing default javascript and jquery in your code which will not work. Try this:

```
function myFunction() {

    var $newDiv = $('<div class="panel panel-default comment"><div class="panel-heading">' + $('#comment_name').val() + '</div><div class="panel-body">' + $('#comment').val() + '</div></div>');

    // if you want the new comment on top of the old ones, use this line
    $newDiv.prependTo('#comment_list');

    // if you want the new comment below the old ones, use this line
    $newDiv.appendTo('#comment_list');

}
```